# Zizaco Entrust 'hasRole' not working within Laravel controller

Tags: laravel, laravel-4

User model:

```
<?php

use Illuminate\Auth\UserInterface;
use Illuminate\Auth\Reminders\RemindableInterface;
use Zizaco\Entrust\HasRole;

class User extends Eloquent implements UserInterface, RemindableInterface {

    use HasRole;
```

Role Model:

```
<?php

use Zizaco\Entrust\EntrustRole;

class Role extends EntrustRole
{

}
```

Permission Model:

```
<?php

use Zizaco\Entrust\EntrustPermission;

class Permission extends EntrustPermission
{

}
```

User controller:

```
public function postSignin(){
        if (Auth::attempt(array('email'=>Input::get('email'),
                                'password'=>Input::get('password')))) {

            $id         = Auth::user()->id;
            $user       = User::where('id','=',$id);
            $firstname = Auth::user()->firstname;

            if ($user->hasRole("User_Not_Approved")) {
                return Redirect::intended('/users/dashboard');
                    }
```

Error message:

> BadMethodCallException
>       Call to undefined method Illuminate\Database\Query\Builder::hasRole()

The error message is presented when the IF statement is running, whilst the user is logging in. I have followed Entrust's instructions, but I am at a loss as to why it isn't picking up the method.

Any help would be hugely appreciated!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try changing:  $user       = User::where('id','=',$id); to $user = User::find($id);

User::where would need ->get to return what you want, and even then it would return a collection; you would want something like User::where(etc)->first(); to ensure you got a single instance of User. In reality though, since you are retrieving by id, that is what ->find($id) is designed for, and what you should do.

Comment: To clarify, ->where is returning a Query Builder object, which is expecting to be chained into other builder methods like more where()'s, sum(), or etc etc. You must 'finish' your query with either a ->get() to return a collection, or ->first() (which would return the first result from your collection). Otherwise ->find() skips all that and is the easiest way to grab something by it's primary key :)

Comment: Thank you, John, that is most helpful. You explain it clearer than the Laravel guide! It works a treat now. Many thanks again.

Comment: No problem, glad I could help! I agree the Laravel docs ended up leaving me with more questions than answers.. it took awhile of playing around to get a proper feel for things. Keep at it and things will begin to make more sense!